# Making a production build of a PHP project with Subversion

Tags: php, svn, scripting, tortoisesvn, build-process

If you are working in PHP (or I guess any programming language) and using subversion as your source control, is there a way to take your project (for example):

> C:\Projects\test\.svn
>   C:\Projects\test\docs\
>   C:\Projects\test\faq.php
>   C:\Projects\test\guestbook.php
>   C:\Projects\test\index.php
>   C:\Projects\test\test.php

and build/copy/whatever it so it weeds out certain files and becomes:

> C:\Projects\test\faq.php
>   C:\Projects\test\guestbook.php
>   C:\Projects\test\index.php

automatically? I'm getting tired of making a branch, and then going through the branch and deleting all of the ".svn" folders, the docs directory, and my prototyping files.

I know I could probably use a .bat file to only copy the specific files I want, but I was hoping there was some way with subversion to sort of pseudo ignore a file, to where it will still version it, but where you could make a snapshot of the project that ignores the files you told it to pseudo ignore.

I know I read online somewhere about some functionality that at least lets you copy without the .svn folders, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use TortoiseSVN, you can use the export feature to automatically strip out all of the .svn files. I think other svn things have the same feature.

Right click the root project folder, then select `TortoiseSVN > Export`, and tell it where you want the `.svn` free directory.

Comment: The export feature *should* work with any client but namely the command line client; it is a standard feature.

Answer (score 2):

Copy all the files manually or using your existing method for the first time.  Then, since I take it you're on a Windows platform, install [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E0FC1154-C975-4814-9649-CCE41AF06EB7&displaylang=en) and configure it in the [subscribe method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncToy#Features), which would effectively one-way copy only the changes made since the last pseudo-commit to production for files already in production.  If you want to add a file you can just copy it manually and resume the SyncToy operation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so my final solution is this:

Use the export command to export to a folder called "export" in the same directory as a file called "deploy.bat", then I run the deploy script (v1 stands for version 1, which is what version I am currently on in this project) This script utilizes 7-Zip, which I have placed on my system path so I can use it as a command line utility:

```
rem replace the v1 directory with the export directory
rd /s /q v1
move /y export\newIMS v1
rd /s /q export

rem remove the prepDocs directory from the project
rd /s /q v1\prepDocs

rem remove the scripts directory from the project
rd /s /q v1\scripts

rem remove individual files from project
del v1\.project
rem del v1\inc\testLoad.html
rem del v1\inc\testInc.js

SET /P version=Please enter version number:

rem zip the file up with 7-Zip and name it after whatever version number the user typed in.
7z a -r v%version%.zip v1

rem copy everything to the shared space ready for deployment
xcopy v%version%.zip /s /q /y /i "Z:\IT\IT Security\IT Projects\IMS\v%version%.zip"
xcopy v1 /s /q /y /i "Z:\IT\IT Security\IT Projects\IMS\currentVersion"

rem keep the window open until user presses any key
PAUSE
```

I didn't have time to check out the SyncToy solution, so don't take this as me rejecting that method. I just knew how to do this, and didn't have time to check that one out (under a time crunch right now).

Sources:

http://commandwindows.com/command2.htm
http://www.ss64.com/nt/